# Using C# Poly framework for Wcf retries, what exceptions are worth retrying?

Tags: c#, wcf, polly, retry-logic

Hi just looking at implementing Poly (found here https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) in our wcf calls for 3rd party api calls.

What exceptions types are worth creating the retry policy for?
So far I have just got TimeoutException.

Is there anymore worth adding?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Probably only worth handling the expected exceptions for WCF calls, `TimeoutException` and `CommunicationException`. Anything else probably indicates an issue with the api call itself, and should be handled in code.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/samples/expected-exceptions